# Web speech reading full content

Tags: services

Am using [WebSpeech](https://www.drupal.org/project/webspeech) Module to convert the text to speech. But when I click on the read content button it reads from the headings, primary tabs instead of main content alone.

In Webspeech configuration the Element ID is "content" class, but still it reads everything.

Any solutions?

Comment: Looking at the code of the Webspeech module and the Webspeech js library you can see that whatever you write in the config page goes from there to `WebSpeech.speakHtml(id)` which then does a `document.getElementById(id)`. Meaning that should make sure you write **content** in the field and that the #content div in your template doesn't include anything you don't want read. If it's still fails it's probably a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Ben.The problem which I found out finally was that I have given the attribute as CLASS name instead of ID. I read somewhere that these field take only ID attribute and do not consider Classes, P and Htags. And for me why it read from title is that, From title to the content bottom its wrapped in a Div Section ID named 'Content'. So the webSpeech was recognizing this ID.